# Where is the "TurboV" manual?

Tags: overclocking

I have a PC with an ASUS P6T SE motherboard and an Intel i7-920 processor.

I noticed that the machine came with some software called "Turbo V" which appears to allow overclocking - but I can't find a manual for the software. Does anyone know how to use this software, or where I can find a manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user manual that came with your ASUS motherboard should have a section with information regarding the usage of Turbo V - at least my ASUS board did, though it was a different model. Regardless, Turbo V is indeed a motherboard overclocking utility for ASUS motherboards.

There are two pretty good sources of information regarding its usage:

1. **[ASUS](http://www.asus.com)**. If you go to support, search in the motherboards section for downloads for your specific model. You should also check their [forums](http://www.asusrog.com/FORUMS).
2. **[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/)**. There are some pretty good videos created by other users on how they are using Turbo V with their boards.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed in the motherboard manual. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Asus P7P55D PRO and the guide for using the TurboV OC Utility is in the user  manual along with the other guides for the rest of the Asus tools at the end if the manual.

Comment: The OP has clearly stated that he cannot find the manual